# Date alert from current date

Tags: r, date, time

Maybe you can help me out with this problem I'm having.

I need to use a code or package that tells me when its been one month or (30 days) since certain date.

Ill give you my data.

```
> Data$Date
 [1] "2015-09-24" "2015-09-26" "2015-10-01" "2015-10-03" "2015-10-09" "2015-10-10" "2015-10-11"
 [8] "2015-10-15" "2015-10-15" "2015-10-16" "2015-10-17" "2015-10-17" "2015-10-18" "2015-10-19"
[15] "2015-10-20" "2015-10-21" "2015-10-22" "2015-10-22" "2015-10-23" "2015-10-24" "2015-10-25"
[22] "2015-10-29" "2015-10-30" "2015-10-31"
```

I need R to point out when its been 30 days since certain day.

For example today (31 october) it would show just this ones.

```
 [1] "2015-09-24" "2015-09-26"
```

I tried couple of things using Sys.Date() but no luck so far.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
Data[which(Sys.Date() - Data$Date > 30), ]

# [1] "2015-09-24" "2015-09-26"
```

Comment: Perfect! I was trying same but missed the last bit! thanks mate